# XMLHttpRequest() has 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it' Error

Tags: php, ajax

I'm writing an XMLHttpRequest function using PHP and AJAX.
However, the error 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.' appears.
I can't detect my problem at all.

```
    echo'<script>';
    
    echo 'function ajaxAction(param){';
    
    echo 'var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();';

    echo 'xmlHttp.open("POST", "http://api.test.co.kr/v1/testpay/card/param/cancel HTTP/1.1", true);';
    echo 'xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "VAN test1:test2");';
    echo 'xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");';
    echo 'xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection","close");';
    echo 'xmlHttp.send(param);';
    
    echo 'xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {';
    echo '  if (xmlHttp.readyState === xmlHttp.DONE){';
    echo '      if (xmlHttp.status === 200){';
    echo '          console.log(xmlHttp.responseText)';
    echo '      } else {';
    echo '          }';
    echo '      }';
    echo '  }';
    

    echo '}';

    echo 'ajaxAction("'.$transactionId.'");';
    echo '</script>';
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with your code, it's a problem with the API.

Comment: @Barmar Is it a problem with the xml file in the api address?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about it. It's just a warning about not being able to display the XML nicely in the browser. It has nothing to do with the regular operation of the API.

Comment: @ Barmar Thank you for your reply.